# Convert files created in Cobol .IDS and .IDX and read from c#

Tags: c#, cobol

A client has asked me if its possible to get data out of an old COBOL program they have recently stopped using. I've taken a quick look and there seems to be lots of .IDS and .IDX files which i assume is the stored data.

I've not used COBOL before are these standard data files?

Is there any simple way to convert them to something i can read via C# or any modern database?

Comment: Your best bet is probably to figure out who the COBOL vendor is and check them out for any conversion utilities that exist.

Comment: They will be standard files for the vendor's implementation of COBOL, not for COBOL per se. So we need to know the vendor for sure. They probably/may have utilities to extract the data to simple files, but you're going to need the COBOL record-layouts to be able to understand the data easily anyway. Does your client have the COBOL source?

Comment: I think they may have access to the source code would i need to rebuild code or is there something in particular i should locate. As i mentioned i don't really know COBOL.

Answer (score 1):

To find out what files a program uses:

Find a line which says `FILE-CONTROL.` Underneath that you will find a SELECT statement for each file used by the program.

```
SELECT internal-file-name ASSIGN TO external-file-name.
```

Either directly, or via the script running the program, external-file-name should all you to match to the filename(s) you are interested in.

Next, find a line which says `FILE SECTION.`

Underneath you will locate an `FD` for each file, which defines the internal-file-name, including the data-mapping (all the stuff under the 01 (there may be more than one 01 per file) which defines the structure of the records on the file.

That's about it. Oh, you will need to understand the layout. Perhaps not, though, as you may be able to use something which *already* understands the layout. If you search for instance of JRecord in the COBOL tag here, should should get some ideas to get you going somewhere.

This presumes there is a utility to extract the data to a flat file.

If you cannot locate a utility (first thing you need to to know the vendor of the compiler, and then find out what is available) then you are going to have to write a very simple COBOL program.